# Why can't browsers resolve the IP of a website?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista, google-chrome, router, dns

I have multiple laptops connected to a router.
3 laptops running windows 7 connect to the internet perfectly.

But 1 laptop with Vista return `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error on any browser.
Skype and Dropbox work fine on the Vista machine. I can also browse using IP but not by address name. so something is wrong with DNS stuff?
Do you know how to fix this issue? I tried a lot of things I read off Google but with no success yet.

**Edits:**

It's just one server I cannot reach with Vista laptop. Outside home, Vista machine connects and works perfect at school and at aiports.. I'm not sure aboub DHCP, I haven't configured anything.

I tried setting DNS servers to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` but it still returns the same error.

This is a problem with multiple webpages not just one.

Pinging `www.google.com` doesn't work but pinging google using its IP works.

Comment: Are you configuring your computers' IP stacks using DHCP? Is it just one server that you can't reach with the Vista laptop or all or?

Answer (score 0):

Skype and dropbox could be working fine if IP addresses for their servers are hardcoded into the software.

Try setting your DNS servers statically to either

- Your router, if it has a DNS server built in or
- Google's DNS servers:

[image]

Comment: It's just one server I cannot reach with Vista laptop. Outside home, Vista machine connects and works perfect at school and at aiports.. I'm not sure aboub DHCP, I haven't configured anything. Thank you! Hi, John T, I tried setting it to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 but it still returns the same error. It seems like it's a reasonable solution but doesn't work on my machine. I wan't sure about my router having DNS, so didn't do anything there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out if it's a problem with the browsers or with DNS generally. Open a command prompt and try each of these, posting back the results:

```
ping google-public-dns-a.google.com    
ping 8.8.8.8
```

If they both work then DNS is set up fine.

If only the second one works then there's a problem with your DNS settings.

Do you get the error message for all web pages, by the way?

If none of this helps then try checking your firewall settings to see if DNS (port 53) is blocked.